# How to correctly select a directory and delete it with its all sub folders and files in PHP

Tags: php

Please answer this question and help me!!

I have found a dozen of code snippets about deleting a folder with its all files and sub folders in PHP. But I am facing difficulties to apply them.

This is an example code :

```
function rrmdir($path) {
 // Open the source directory to read in files
    $i = new DirectoryIterator($path);
    foreach($i as $f) {
        if($f->isFile()) {
            unlink($f->getRealPath());
        } else if(!$f->isDot() && $f->isDir()) {
            rrmdir($f->getRealPath());
        }
    }
    rmdir($path);
}
```

I can not understand how to write the source directory. I mean, how I set the $path variable? All the files of my website is inside 'public_html' folder. Will I include 'public_html' also?

When I want to delete a folder inside 'usercontent' folder, I am writing like this :

```
$path = "/usercontent/somefolder"
```

Please answer with an example directory path.

**Update:** What should be the permission of the folder which will be deleted.

Comment: Maybe duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594180/deleting-all-files-from-a-folder-using-php?rq=1

Comment: one more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613840/remove-all-files-folders-and-their-subfolders-with-php

Comment: I have seen these answers. Please tell me how to write the directory path correctly.

Comment: Do you know your path on the server? Normally something like /var/www/vhosts/yourvhost/public_html/.

You should be able to see this by putting this code in your index.php:

echo dirname(_ _ FILE _ _);

Without the spaces inside of the dirname function.

Comment: I know the path. But I am having problem to implement it. I can not understand why the code is not working. Where to set the $path variable? Please help.