# How to delete all .gif images from subdirectory

Tags: php

I like to delete all .gif images from subdirectory i tried with [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

but its getting only 1st level subdirectory

```
$dirs = array_filter(glob('main/*'), 'is_dir');
```

but i have directory like this

```
Main 
Sub 1
 Sub 1-2
  Sub 1-3
   Sub 1-4
Sub 2
 Sub 2-1
Sub 3
Sub 4
 Sub 4-1
  Sub 4-2
   Sub 4-3
```

How to check in all subdirectory and delete only .gif images ?

Comment: I think this post <here> should help you get the base set. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613840/remove-all-files-folders-and-their-subfolders-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the answer in the link :

```
<?php
    function rrmdir($dir) {
        if (is_dir($dir)) {
            $objects = scandir($dir);
            foreach ($objects as $object) {
                if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
                    // here we can check the mime_content_type for the gif 
                    if (mime_content_type($dir."/".$object) == "image/gif") 
                        rrmdir($dir."/".$object); 
                    else unlink   ($dir."/".$object);
                }
            }
           reset($objects);
           rmdir($dir);
       }
   }
?>
```

To check the content or file type ; we can use 'mime_content_type()'.
This method returns 'image/gif' for the gif.

reference link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Using the method 'rrmdir()' as the base reference, we can hierarchically find the gif files and delete them.